# MCMCglmm binomial model prior

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, mcmc

I want to estimate a binomial model with the `R` package `MCMCglmm`. The model shall incorporate an intercept and a slope - both as fixed and random parts. How do I have to specify an accepted `prior`? (Note, [here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227467/mcmcglmm-multinomial-model-in-r), but in a much more complicated setting.)

Assume the data have the following form:

```
  y           x cluster
1 0 -0.56047565       1
2 1 -0.23017749       1
3 0  1.55870831       1
4 1  0.07050839       1
5 0  0.12928774       1
6 1  1.71506499       1
```

---

In fact, the data have been generated by

```
set.seed(123)
nj <- 15 # number of individuals per cluster
J <- 30  # number of clusters
n <- nj * J
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, prob = 0.6)
cluster <- factor(rep(1:nj, each = J))

dat <- data.frame(y = y, x = x, cluster = cluster)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information in the question about the model, suggest to specify `fixed = y ~ 1 + x` and `random =  ~ us(1 + x):cluster`. With `us()` you allow the random effects to be correlated (cf. section 3.4 and table 2 in [Hadfield's 2010 jstatsoft-article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v033i02/v33i02.pdf))

First of all, as you only have one dependent variable (`y`), the **G** part in the prior (cf. equation 4 and section 3.6 in [Hadfield's 2010 jstatsoft-article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v033i02/v33i02.pdf)) for the random effects variance(s) only needs to have one list element called `G1`. This list element isn't the actual prior distribution - this was specified by Hadfield to be an [inverse-Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution). But with `G1` you specify the parameters of this inverse-Whishart distribution which are the scale matrix ([image] in Wikipedia notation and `V` in `MCMCglmm` notation) and the degrees of freedom ([image] in Wikipedia notation and `nu` in `MCMCglmm` notation). As you have two random effects (the intercept and the slope) `V` has to be a 2 x 2 matrix. A frequent choice is the two dimensional identity matrix `diag(2)`. Hadfield often uses `nu = 0.002` for the degrees of freedom (cf. [his course notes](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf))

Now, you also have to specify the **R** part in the prior for the residual variance. Here again an inverse-Whishart distribution was specified by Hadfield, leaving the user to specify its parameters. As we only have one residual variance, `V` has to be a scalar (lets say `V = 0.5`). An optional element for `R` is `fix`. With this element you specify, whether the residual variance shall be fixed to a certain value (than you have to write `fix = TRUE` or `fix = 1`) or not (then `fix = FALSE` or `fix = 0`). Notice, that you don't fix the residual variance to be `0.5` by `fix = 0.5`! So when you find in Hadfield's course notes `fix = 1`, read it as `fix = TRUE` and look to which value of `V` it is was fixed.

**All togehter we set up the prior as follows:**

```
prior0 <- list(G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 0.002)),
               R = list(V = 0.5, nu = 0.002, fix = FALSE))
```

With this prior we can run `MCMCglmm`:

```
library("MCMCglmm") # for MCMCglmm()    
set.seed(123) 

mod0 <- MCMCglmm(fixed = y ~ 1 + x, 
            random =  ~ us(1 + x):cluster, 
            data = dat,
            family = "categorical",
            prior = prior0)
```

The draws from the Gibbs-sampler for the fixed effects are found in `mod0$Sol`, the draws for the variance parameters in `mod0$VCV`.

Normally a binomial model requires the residual variance to be fixed, so we set the residual variance to be fixed at `0.5`

```
set.seed(123)

prior1 <- list(G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 0.002)),
          R = list(V = 0.5, nu = 0.002, fix = TRUE))

mod1 <- MCMCglmm(fixed = y ~ 1 + x, 
            random =  ~ us(1 + x):cluster, 
            data = dat,
            family = "categorical",
            prior = prior1)
```

The difference can be seen by comparing `mod0$VCV[, 5]` to `mod1$VCV[, 5]`. In the later case, all entries are `0.5` as specified.